# How fast does time elapse when you're not actively playing SimCity BuildIt?

Tags: simcity-buildit

It seems to me that when you you're not actively playing (so, you don't have the app open on your phone), time elapses at a different rate, not in real-time. I've started production on things that claim to take 30 minutes, but when I go back to the game more than 30 minutes later, they're still in production.

Am I imagining this, or does time slow down when the game isn't active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game uses your device's clock. It subtracts the time you started from the current time to determine if a timer should have completed when you restart your game. If your device time is changed this will be reflected. For example, if you advance your clock, then timers will be reduced by this amount. **DO NOT DO THIS, it only works if offline, and when you go back online it will rollback your game.**

I have timed this myself, because I felt the same way, and they do not advance any faster or slower when playing online. There is sometimes a case, similar to what you mention, when you play offline for a while, then play online, it will resync the game play (and may even rollback your progress), this has happened to me.

Be aware that if you spend a lot of time offline/out of service the chance of desync and rollback increases. Most mobile phones and tablets have terrible chronometers that will lose time often a much as 1 minute per day or more. They depend on cell service and WiFi to set the clocks periodically. If you find you have frequent rollbacks or timers that take a while this is something to be aware of. Some cell phones only set their clock when calls are received, so even if it's on if you don't receive calls or messages your clock may be off and this will affect the games times as well.

Comment: I agree. This has happened to me as well. Great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say that you're imagining it, as I play the game as well and haven't experienced this personally.

It could be that you're thinking more time has passed since you started your production, since you - generally speaking - can't see the time when you're playing a game.

Comment: I agree, not that I've ever timed it, but it has always appeared to be exactly real-time.